# Complex Matrix and its Conjugate terms

Tags: matrices

If $z = \left| {\begin{array}{*{20}{c}}
{3 + 2i}&1&i\\
2&{3 - 2i}&{1 + i}\\
{1 - i}&{ - i}&3
\end{array}} \right|\& \left| {z + \overline z } \right| = k\left| z \right|$, find the value of k

My approach is as follow

$ \Rightarrow z =  - \left| {\begin{array}{*{20}{c}}
1&{3 + 2i}&i\\
{3 - 2i}&2&{1 + i}\\
{ - i}&{1 - i}&3
\end{array}} \right|$ where $\left( {{C_1} \leftrightarrow {C_2}} \right)$

$ \Rightarrow \overline z  =  - \left| {\begin{array}{*{20}{c}}
1&{3 - 2i}&{ - i}\\
{3 + 2i}&2&{1 - i}\\
i&{1 + i}&3
\end{array}} \right|$

How do we proceed from here.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You already exchanged the first two columns, which is a good start. The corresponding matrix
$$
A = \begin{pmatrix}
1&{3 + 2i}&i\\
{3 - 2i}&2&{1 + i}\\
{ - i}&{1 - i}&3\end{pmatrix}
$$
has the property that $A^T$ is the elementwise conjugate of $A$, so that
$$
 \det(A) = \det(A^T) = \overline{\det(A)} \, .
$$

It follows that $z = -\det(A)$ is a *real* number, and therefore is $|z + \bar z| =2|z|$.

Answer (score 1):

Since $z=27$, $\left|z+\overline z\right|=2\times27$, and therefore $k=2$.

Comment: can you elaborate what property you use, I also got this answer but I would like to solve it by using determinant propertry

Comment: I simply *computed* the determinant.